From where does the formula “$\frac{P^2}{48}$" to find no. of triangles with integer sides comes?
From where does the formula $\frac{P^2}{48} $ to find no. of triangles with integer sides having an even perimeter "$P$"comes from?. I didn't get any answer for this on the internet. I am currently in high school so I have no idea from where does this come and gives an approximate answer? It works so well for all the even perimeters I have tested ,you just have to round off the answer to the  nearest integer after you compute it for any even perimeter.

Nice question. Are you interested in the intuition behind why the count should be approximately $\frac{P^2}{48}$ or in proving that the formula works? (These are slightly different questions.)

See A005044 for some useful properties of the sequence.

As I mentioned in my comment, there are really two related questions here: the first is "what is the formula for the number of triangles with a given perimeter?" and the second (which really comes once you've seen the formula) "why does it involve $\frac{P^2}{48}$?". The reason I'd separate these is that the case analysis involved in the first can divert from the geometric intuition involved in the second.
For clarity, we are interested in the number of solutions in positive integers to $a+b+c=P$ where $a \le b \le c$ and $a+b>c$ (it's important to order the sidelengths to avoid double-counting).
To answer the first question, let's say we're given a perimeter $P$ and we choose a particular value of $a$. Since $a$ is the shortest side, we'd better make sure that $a\le \frac{P}{3}$. How many ways can we choose a second side $b\ge a$ and third side $c=P-a-b$ that satisfy both $b\le c$ and $a+b>c$?
Since $c=P-a-b$, for $b\le c$ we must have $2b\le P-a$. From $a+b>c$, we get $2b>P-2a$, in other words $P-2a+1\le 2b$. But we also need $b\ge a$. Putting all of these together,
$$\max(P-2a+1,2a)\le 2b \le P-a$$
so there are $P-a-\max(P-2a+1,2a)+1$ values of $b$ that work.
As an example, for $P=22$ and $a=6$, we find
$$12\le 2b \le 16$$
which has three solutions ($b=6$, $b=7$, $b=8$) and you can verify these all give triangles.
This gives a way to get the number of triangles with perimeter $P$: we need to sum the quantity $P-a-\max(P-2a+1,2a)+1$ over all $a\le \frac{P}{3}$.
This is doable, but involves a bit of casework. For instance, you can see that the sum will look slightly different depending on the parity of $P$. There are lots of good links from the OEIS page for this sequence.
If you go through all the cases, you'll find an exact formula can be written as $\frac{P^2}{48}$ plus a linear expression in $P$ that depends on the remainder when you divide $P$ by $12$.
(To me) the more interesting question is why $\frac{P^2}{48}$ shows up.

To understand this, let's go back to the key inequalities we found in terms of $a$, $b$ and $P$. These are
\begin{align*}
a&\le b\\
2b&\le P-a\\
P-2a&< 2b
\end{align*}
These three inequalities define a triangular region in the $(a,b)$ plane. The count of valid triangles is equal to the number of lattice points inside this region; and the area of this region is $\frac{P^2}{48}$.

TL;DR: for a given perimeter $P$, write down the inequalities satisfied by the side lengths $a$ and $b$. Draw these in the $(a,b)$ plane and work out the area of the region they define.

Is this formula works for ALL even parameters if rounded off to the nearest integer? And also as per your calculation it seems you didn't consider P to be even or odd. You generalized it. But the formula we have for odd parameters is different (P+3)^2/48 why?
